# config.assets.debug = true doesnt work

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

It started happening that config.assets.debug = true on development doesnt work.

Instead of many separated javascript/css files inclusions I get this:

```
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js"></script>
```

Any idea what has gone wrong AND/OR how can I debug the issue?

Development settings:

```
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.digest = false

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.compress = false
```

Everything starts working as expected if I set

```
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.assets.compile = true
```

Can someone explain why?

Comment: You have a colon after "this" but you don't seem to paste the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

config.assets.compile = true

Setting should be set to true since I HAVE TO compile scss - I use SASS for stylesheet files.

Comment: github.com/rails/sprockets/issues/162 - there's a bug on this, particularly application.css